# Xgboost Installation error on windows .OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, machine-learning, installation, data-science, xgboost

I am trying to install Xgboost on a windows 10 PC, I followed each and every step as per installation [guide](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html)
All the installation processes have been completed, but I'm getting an error while importing the library:

> OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found

[image: error]

how does one fix this problem? I am using anaconda with python 3.6. Can anyone help me to figure this out? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried another method. I installed trough anaconda navigator by typing **conda install -c rdonnelly py-xgboost** in anaconda navigator.It works and xgboost library imported successfully.

Answer (score -1):

conda install -c rdonnelly py-xgboost in anaconda prompt as Administrator. It worked for me too to resolve above OSError

Comment: You can also try :  conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost  , in anaconda prompt as Administrator.